# Detecting touch input regions in Unity

Tags: c#, input, unity-game-engine, touch

This is for a simple game of Pong. The script is added to both paddles, and what I wanted to do was to make the paddles move via touch inputs along regions of the screen.

Upper-left region: left paddle up

Lower-left region: left paddle down

Upper-right region: right paddle up

Lower-right region: right paddle down

For some reason, whatever I do simply move the right paddle up. I would like to do some proper debugging but I have no idea how to debug touches aside from loading the APK to my phone and experimenting with actual touches.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MovePaddle : MonoBehaviour {

public KeyCode Up;
public KeyCode Down;

void FixedUpdate () {
    if (Input.GetKey (Up)) {
        transform.Translate(new Vector2(0.0f, 0.5f));
    }

    if (Input.GetKey (Down)) {
        transform.Translate(new Vector2(0.0f, -0.5f));
    }

    if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Stationary) {
        TouchEval(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
    }
}

void TouchEval (Vector2 pos) {  
    if (pos.x < 0 && gameObject.name == "paddleLeft") {
        if (pos.y > 0) {
            transform.Translate(new Vector2(0.0f, 0.5f));
        } 
        else {
            transform.Translate(new Vector2(0.0f, -0.5f));
        }
    }

    if (pos.x > 0 && gameObject.name == "paddleRight") {
        if (pos.y > 0) {
            transform.Translate(new Vector2(0.0f, 0.5f));
        } 
        else {
            transform.Translate(new Vector2(0.0f, -0.5f));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Oops, I ran some sensor apps and apparently the vertex is 0,0 at the bottom left corner. Originally I assumed 0,0 was at the center, which was why I checked the polarity of the coordinates. I did not know that.

Comment: It is the same with monitors.

Comment: Ah, is it? This is my first time coding something that requires resolution numbers. I probably made the wrong assumption since that was the way it's done in Unity (0,0 at the center).